# How can I make a field in a class be set to false if the value being set is a null?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have the following:

```
var result2 = result1
          .Select((t, index) => new  {
             Answer = t.Answer,
             Answers = JSON.FromJSONString<Answer2>(t.AnswerJSON)
          });
          return Ok(result2);

    public class Answer2 {
        public bool? Correct; // Maybe this should be a property
        public bool Response; // Maybe this should be a property
    }
```

And my String > object function:

```
    public static T FromJSONString<T>(this string obj) where T : class
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(obj)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            T ret = (T)ser.ReadObject(stream);
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way with this that I could make the Response field be false if a null is present for Response in the JSON string or if there is no value for Response in the JSON string?

Note: I had a suggestion about using a property and I think that would work but I am not sure how to do it in practice.

Comment: I don't think you can do such thing without using a property

Comment: @Alireza - Yes maybe that is my mistake. I think it would work okay if I used a property. Could you give me an example?

Comment: how about make your Response `bool?` and a Property so you could handle `null` in the setter part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a property for this matter:

```
public class Answer2 {
    private bool correct;  // This field has no need to be nullable
    public bool? Correct
    {
        get { return correct; }
        set { correct = value.GetValueOrDefault(); }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the Q and A section, you should be able to do it on a property like this:

```
private bool? whatever;
public bool? Whatever
{
   get { return whatever; }
   set
   {
       if (value == null)
          whatever = false;
       else
          whatever = value;
   }
}
```

This way you can pass a `null` value to the property, but it can only have a `bool` (true/false) value in it.

Comment: Or simply `set { this.whatever = value ?? false; }`

Comment: I'm too used to the stylecop/fxcop rules of my company, sadly, I cannot that :(

Comment: Since when does stylecop forbid the `??` operator? IIRC, no braces around code blocks is usually highlighted by stylecop (so it should be `if(...) { ... } else { ... }` instead of `if(...) ... else ...`)

Comment: I know that you can configure the stylecop rules. Although I don't see any benefit in disallowing language features. Nevermind, it's not relevant for the question, it was just a hint how to shorten the code.

Comment: Believe me, I asked the same thing you are asking me know on my first day on the job... their reasoning was for readability purposes (same as using brackets on ifs even if they only contain one line of code).